# Getting list of QGIS field names, not including hidden fields using PyQGIS

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis

Currently, for a python plugin for QGIS 2.8.3, I get the list of fields for a layer using pendingFields as mentioned in this [thread](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/76364/how-to-get-field-names-in-pyqgis-2-0):

```
fields = self.layer.pendingFields()
```

I now have a few hidden fields (set via the fields tab in layer properties). How can I get a list of fields that are not hidden?

I see the possibility to get Edit Type, but am not sure where to go from here :

```
EditType { 
  LineEdit, UniqueValues, UniqueValuesEditable, ValueMap, 
  Classification, EditRange, SliderRange, CheckBox, 
  FileName, Enumeration, Immutable, Hidden, 
  TextEdit, Calendar, DialRange, ValueRelation, 
  UuidGenerator, Photo, WebView, Color, 
  EditorWidgetV2 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The vector layer object has a [`editorWidgetV2ByName`](http://qgis.org/api/classQgsVectorLayer.html#a22b98b83cfc351f307c0cb7d7672976a) method which allows you to pass in a field name and get back the the name of the Edit Widget as a string. For example:

```python
>>> layer.editorWidgetV2ByName("fieldname")
'Hidden'
```

Alternately there is the `editorWidgetV2` method which allows you to pass in a field index:

```python
>>> layer.editorWidgetV2(0)
'Hidden'
```

The list of names for different widgets can be found with the documentation for [`setEditorWidgetV2`](http://qgis.org/api/classQgsVectorLayer.html#a05a33f4d4f9953571f680f6b18589559), which incidently can be used to set the widget for a field given the index, like so:

```python
>>> layer.setEditorWidgetV2(0, "Hidden")
```

So to get a list of fields which aren't hidden you can use the following snippet:

```python
fields = [
    field for field in layer.pendingFields()
    if layer.editorWidgetV2ByName(field.name() != "Hidden")
]
```