# PyQGIS equivalent for ArcPy ListFields

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, list, pycharm

I just started using PyQGIS and I am not familiar with many of the commands.

In ArcPy, you can use the command arcpy.ListFields to print out the fields present in a shapefile. I'm wondering if there is an equivalent command in PyQGIS?

I am working in Python 3.6 and QGIS 3.0 Girona.

Comment: In python2.7, you can use `layer.getFields()`, that will return a [QgsFields](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsFields.html) object. The you can use `QgsFields.toList()` to iterate over all `QgsField`. Basically, if you want to get a list of field names use `[field.name() for field in layer.getFields().toList()]`. But I do not know if this works for QGis 3.0

Comment: This is more relevant for QGIS 2.X but have you tried what is suggested here? https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/76364/how-to-get-field-names-in-pyqgis-2-0

Answer (score 5):

QgsVectorLayer class has a fields method for it.
Using the QGIS Python console you can try this code (the current layer should be a vector layer (instance of QgsVectorLayer)):

```
>>> layer = iface.activeLayer()
>>> layer
<qgis._core.QgsVectorLayer object at 0x7f5e031ccc18>
>>> layer.fields()
<qgis._core.QgsFields object at 0x7f5e031ccca8>
>>> print (layer.fields()[0])
<qgis._core.QgsField object at 0x7f5e031deca8>
>>> for field in layer.fields():
...    print(field.name(), field.typeName())
name String
id Integer
area Integer64
```

For further information see https://qgis.org/api/classQgsField.html and https://qgis.org/api/classQgsFields.html

Comment: Judging from the tags, I think she's trying to do this in an IDE outside of the builtin python console. Other than selecting later via iface, would the steps be the same?